Provide bash vars or at least develop ~ through let variable
To activate lsp I use this on my .vimrc:
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
  Plug 'yegappan/lsp'
call plug#end()
let lspOpts = #{autoHighlightDiags: v:true}
autocmd User LspSetup call LspOptionsSet(lspOpts)

let lspServers = [#{ name: 'pylsp',
                 \   filetype: 'python',
                 \   path: '/home/me/.pyenv/versions/lsp/bin/pylsp',
                 \   args: ['--verbose', '--log-file',  '/tmp/out_lsp.log'],
                 \ }] 
autocmd User LspSetup call LspAddServer(lspServers)

Because this .vimrc is used across multiples users I would like to be able to use
\   path: '~/.pyenv/versions/lsp/bin/pylsp',

But id does not work.
I've try:
\   path: 'glob(~/.pyenv/versions/lsp/bin/pylsp)',

and
\   path: '$HOME/.pyenv/versions/lsp/bin/pylsp',

with no chance.

I would use the expand() function.
It expands environment variables (expand('$HOME/.pyenv):
let lspServers = [#{ name: 'pylsp',
                 \   filetype: 'python',
                 \   path: expand('$HOME/.pyenv/versions/lsp/bin/pylsp'),
                 \   args: ['--verbose', '--log-file',  '/tmp/out_lsp.log'],
                 \ }] 

But also the ~ special character (expand('~/.pyenv')):
let lspServers = [#{ name: 'pylsp',
                 \   filetype: 'python',
                 \   path: expand('~/.pyenv/versions/lsp/bin/pylsp'),
                 \   args: ['--verbose', '--log-file',  '/tmp/out_lsp.log'],
                 \ }] 

More information with :help expand().
